# How can I match a regex with a pattern and arbitary amount of times?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, tokenize

I current have a regular expression defined as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile("(\d+:)+(\d+)")
>>> search_results = regex.search("52345:54325432:555:443:3:33")
>>> search_results.groups()
('3:', '33')
```

I know I could do

```
>>> "52345:54325432:555:443:3:33".split(":")
```

for splitting each item into tokens, but I want to know how I could achieve this using a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` if you want all the matches, `re.search` stops at the first match.:

```
>>> strs = "52345:54325432:555:443:3:33"
>>> re.findall(r"(\d+):(\d+)",strs)
[('52345', '54325432'), ('555', '443'), ('3', '33')]
```

If you want the exact same result as `str.split` then you could do:

```
>>> re.split(r":",strs)
['52345', '54325432', '555', '443', '3', '33']
>>> re.findall(r"[^:]+",strs)
['52345', '54325432', '555', '443', '3', '33']
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps...

```
>>> pat = r'(\d+(?=\:)|\d+$)'
>>> regexp = re.compile(pat)
>>> m = regexp.findall("52345:54325432:555:443:3:33")
>>> m
['52345', '54325432', '555', '443', '3', '33']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `split` to solve this problem.

`findall` would work on any valid string. Unfortunately, it would also work on any invalid string. If that's what you want, fine; but probably you want to know if there was an error.

Examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> digits = re.compile("\d+")
>>> digits.findall("52345:54325432:555:443:3:33")
['52345', '54325432', '555', '443', '3', '33']
>>> digits.findall("52345:54325.432:555:443:3:33")
['52345', '54325', '432', '555', '443', '3', '33']
>>> digits.findall(""There are 2 numbers and 53 characters in this string."")
['2', '53']
```

Of course, you could first match and then split, if you were determined to only use the `re`  module:

```
>>> valid = re.compile("(?:\d+:)*\d+$")
>>> digits = re.compile("\d+")
>>> s = "52345:54325432:555:443:3:33"
>>> digits.findall(s) if valid.match(s) else []
```

In contrast:

```
>>> [int(n) for n in "52345:54325432:555:443:3:33".split(":")]
[52345, 54325432, 555, 443, 3, 33]
>>> [int(n) for n in "52345:54325.432:555:443:3:33".split(":")]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '54325.432'

>>> [int(n)
...  for n in "There are 2 numbers and 53 characters in this string.".split(":")]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
  'There are 2 numbers and 53 characters in this string.'
```

Comment: I know split is generally the right choice, but I am curious how you do it otherwise. It's a regex problem, not how pythonic I can be, not matter how nice being pythonic is.

Comment: @user1876508: it's not really a regex problem. You know how to recognize the string with a regex, since you wrote that. The question "how do I split the string in a single call to a regex method in python" has no answer; there is no such api. If you tested the string for correctness first, you could use the simple findall in my answer to split it; perhaps that's the answer you're looking for (although it is two calls, not one).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<test>[0-9]+):
```

this is the regex. what you will have to do is this:
e.g. you string is in str:

```
var str = "52345:54325432:555:443:3:33";
```

then you will have to match this string with regex in while loop

```
while(RegexMatch.Success){
```

//    operations here
}

the first value: i.e: 52345 will be in:

```
var first = RegexMatch.Groups["test"].Value;
```

for first alteration.

Note: this is not the exact code to match the Regex etc. but a psuedo code. Hope you understand. I am attaching image to show the groups in regex.
[image]